# Regex - Ignore lines with matching text

Tags: regex

I need the RegEx command to get all the lines which DO NOT have the job name containing "filewatch". Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

```
STATUS: FAILURE         JOB: i3-imds-dcp-pd-bo1-05-ftpfilewatcher
STATUS: FAILURE         JOB: i3-cur-atmrec-pd-TD_FTP_Forecast_File_Del_M_Su
ALARM: JOBFAILURE       JOB: i3-cur-atmrec-pd-TD_FTP_Forecast_File_Del_M_Su
STATUS: FAILURE         JOB: i3-sss-system-heartbeat
ALARM: JOBFAILURE       JOB: i3-sss-system-heartbeat
STATUS: FAILURE         JOB: i3-chq-cspo-pd-batch-daily-renametable-fileok
STATUS: FAILURE         JOB: i3-chq-cspo-pd-batch-daily-renametable-file
ALARM: JOBFAILURE       JOB: i3-chq-cspo-pd-batch-daily-renametable-fileok
ALARM: JOBFAILURE       JOB: i3-chq-cspo-pd-batch-daily-renametable-file
STATUS: FAILURE         JOB: i3-imds-dcp-pd-bo1-35-filewatcher
STATUS: FAILURE         JOB: i3-imds-dcp-pd-bo1-05-ftpfilewatcher
STATUS: FAILURE         JOB: i3-imds-dcp-pd-bo1-35-filewatcher
STATUS: FAILURE         JOB: i3-imds-dcp-pd-bo1-05-ftpfilewatcher
```

Comment: What language or command are you working with? On many systems, `grep -v filewatch` would be all that you'd need.

Answer (score 3):

If your regular expression implementation supports [look-ahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead), try this:

```
^(STATUS|ALARM): +(JOB)?FAILURE +JOB: ((?!filewatch).)+$
```

Make sure that `^` and `$` match the <del>file</del> *line* begin/end.

Comment: Don't you mean that `^` and `$` should match the beginning and end of each *line*?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: Ah yes, of course! I meant line but wrote file. ;-)